# CSS Background Image on top of image banner in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently tweaking the stylesheet of an online conference website so it looks better. I will be using Chrome's "Inspect Element" feature combined with the "Stylish" plugin to create & save the new stylesheet and then have Chrome replace the preexisting stylesheet with my edited version, client-side (i.e. the function of the plugin). The one area I'm having difficulty with is replacing the image banner, as it's an image in the HTML of the page instead of on the stylesheet (see screenshot):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp6RW.jpg

I am able to set a background image in the "bannerimgcell" class, but the http://mt215.sabameeting.com/SiteRoots/main/AgendaStorageRoot/Cobranding/000000ec87840000010d66d1e20a8001/En/US/Images/Banner.gif image remains on top of it. Is there any way to position a background image for this class **on top** of the image, so that it looks like a new image banner is there?

EDIT: Sorry if I'm not being clear. I'm trying to put a new header image over the preexisting one via CSS.

Comment: i'm really having dificulties to understand what you're trying to archieve, can u please try to be clearer in what you want to do

Comment: A little confused over what you're trying to achieve here, as you have to be careful with the words image, and background-image. Standard `z-index` tricks would place an element containing a background image, up and above anything beneath it, but I'm not sure if that's what you are thinking of here.

Comment: A **background** image *on top* of something, now I've heard everything.

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to put a new header image over the preexisting one via CSS. (or replace it, if that's possible.)

Comment: Can be done in CSS with the ::after pseudo element.

Comment: Why are you still loading a now useless HTML image? Why aren't you replacing by another HTML image? BTW this isn't presentation but content: the name of the conference it seems; so an HTML image with its `alt` attribute read out by screen readers and perceived and indexed by searchbots would be far better here.

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript Solution:**

You can change the image source:

```
var newImg = "http://mt215.sabameeting.com/SiteRoots/main/AgendaStorageRoot/Cobranding/000000ec87840000010d66d1e20a8001/En/US/Images/Banner.gif"
document.getElementsByClassName('bannerimgcell')[0].setAttribute('src', newImg);
```

As the render layers are composed your CSS background will be below the img src.
Not really sure if this code will work. I am assuming that 'bannerimgcell' is the class of the img tag and its the first one.

**CSS Solution:**

```
.bannerimgcell:after { 
    background-image: url('someNewImg.gif');
   /* width, height and position to match the overlaid element */ 
}
```

Comment: I have so much to learn. I'll try this, thank you! So this overrides the image URL of the old banner embedded in the HTML as well?

Comment: Yes, this should replace your old image with the new one.

Comment: Make sure that you replace the newImg variable with the url to your new image

Comment: Okay. And would I paste this code in the stylesheet, under the bannerimgcell class?

Comment: This should be add in your script element: <script>/*Code goes here*/</script>

Comment: Hey, so I'm trying both the JS and CSS solutions and neither seem to be working... So looking at the CSS solution, should I make a new .bannerimgcell class or? Because the only bannerimgcell in the stylesheet is "TD.bannerimgcell" . Here's the whole stylesheet I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/vnzb1fkU

Comment: No not really but will do. Here is a fiddle with the Javascript solution. Just add this into your Javascript code: http://jsfiddle.net/aYWLA/1/

Comment: Can I add JS code into the stylesheet though? Just to clarify, I'm only able to edit the stylesheet for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is using:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
background-image: url('yourimage.jpg');
```

That would place whatever element is styled by those rules, up and above anything below it, provided that the element beneath it has a lower `z-index` (by default it would).

`position:absolute` means that you'll have to manually place the new CSS element over the existing content, and make sure that all the widths and heights align so that you don't see the old image below.